# No logro importar mi modulo .py

Tags: python, pylance

No logro importar mi paquete .py. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
from Proyecto.Clases import Persona
```

Y el directorio es el siguiente, (el archivo desde donde quiero importar se llama `probarClases.py` y se encuentra ubicado en la carpeta `Python`):

```
Python/Proyecto/Clases
```

Tanto en Python, como en Proyecto y en Clases tengo los archivos `__init__.py`.

El error que me sale es

```
Import "Proyecto.Clases" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)
```

Comment: podrias poner la estructura(como una imagen) de tu proyecto (directorios), ademas podrias mostrar el contenido del archivo que intentas importar, tal vez haces un uso inadecuado de la clase que deseas

Comment: Ese mensaje es un warning del servidor de lenguaje. Es decir, tu módulo probablemente si se está importando (tienes que ejecutar el script para saberlo), pero el servidor de lenguaje te está informando que no logra resolverlo y por tanto no podrá ofrecerte _ayuda_ en el _code insight_.
He agregado la etiqueta _pylance_ a la pregunta, por la misma razón.

Comment: @Jesus, me llama la atención que tienes publicadas varias preguntas y ninguna tiene una respuesta aceptada, quizás no te has dado cuenta, pero [el sitio funciona de esa manera](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Si no sabes como hacerlo, te invito a darte una vuelta por el [tour]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje es un *warning* generado por el servidor de lenguaje de Python, que es Pylance y te está diciendo que no pudo resolver el nombre del módulo que estás importando y, por tanto, Intellisense no contendrá información sobre el mismo.

No lo está encontrando porque probablemente `Python`, que es donde está tu archivo `probasrClases.py`, no es la carpeta raíz, la [documentación sobre _Unresolved import warnings](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#unresolved-import-warnings) dice, entre otras cosas:

> The language server treats the workspace root (i.e. folder you have opened) as the main root of user module imports. This means that if your imports are not relative to this path, the language server will not be able to find them.
>
> These extra roots must be specified to the language server. The easiest way to do this (with the VS Code Python extension) is to create a workspace configuration which sets `python.analysis.extraPaths`. For example, if a project uses a `sources` directory, then create a file `.vscode/settings.json` in the workspace with the contents:
>
> ```
> {
>    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./sources"]
> }
> ```

Mi traducción y énfasis libre es:

> El servidor de lenguaje trata la carpeta raíz del espacio de trabajo (es decir, la carpeta que has abierto) como la raíz principal de las importaciones de módulos de usuario. Esto significa que si tus importaciones no son relativas a esta ruta, el servidor de lenguaje no podrá encontrarlas.
>
> Estas raíces adicionales deben especificarse al servidor de lenguage. La forma más fácil de hacerlo (con la extensión Python de VS Code) es crear una configuración de espacio de trabajo (*workspace configuration*) que establezca la variable `python.analysis.extraPaths`. Por ejemplo, si un proyecto utiliza un directorio `sources`, crea un archivo `.vscode/settings.json` en el espacio de trabajo con el siguiente contenido:
>
> ```
> {
>    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./sources"]
> }
> ```

OJO, que he omitido partes del texto para quedarme con lo esencial, considero que debieras leerlo completo.

En resumen, si tu *Workspace* resultara ser la carpeta *padre* de `Python`, por ejemplo si la estructura completa de tus archivos fuera:

```
c:\source\Ejercicio
                |-> Python
                       |-> Proyecto
                                |-> Clases
```

Tendrías que crear la carpeta `c:\source\Ejercicio\.vscode`, dentro crear el archivo `settings.json` y dentro de ese archivo colocar el texto siguiente:

```
{
   "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./Python"]
}
```

Reinicia el VSCode (desconozco si puede agarrar esto *al vuelo*, así que vamos a la segura, y ya con eso debiera ser capaz de ubicar el archivo.